# Regex according before text (subdomain + domain + ext)

Tags: php, regex

I want to validate these strings

```
dkfi.fr
dje_uf.fkeid.fr
dkei.fkei.fr
```

Because the subdomain can contain underscores but domaine + ext can't.

I have done this regex :

```
^([0-9a-z\-_\.]+)*(\.[0-9a-z\-]+){2,}$
```

But it doesn't validate dkfi.fr because the point \. after * is required.
I don't want to put \.? because this wrong string will be accepted : "djeud.kd_dk.fr"

I want the point is not required if the first part (before *) is not validate, so if we are at the begin of string.

Comment: it's because of `(\.[0-9a-z\-]+){2,}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex to:

```
^([0-9a-z_-]+\.)*([0-9a-z-]+\.[0-9a-z-]+)$
```

Comment: be carefully with cyrillic domain names

Answer (score 0):

Symfony framework uses that pattern for domain matching.

```
~^([\pL\pN\pS-]+\.)+[\pL]+$~ixu
```

In full version it also allow to use IP and port: 
[github source](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.7/src/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints/UrlValidator.php)

For your needs you can just add part with underscore

```
~^([\pL\pN\pS_-]+\.)*([\pL\pN\pS-]+\.)+[\pL]+$~ixu
```